# My Ubuntu guest system is no longer picking up the Host-only network in virtualbox

Tags: macos, ubuntu, virtualbox

I managed to briefly get this working before, but I was messing around with creating these via the command line and was deleting and creating them and now it's stopped working. This is what I've tried so far:

1. Delete the Host-only network and re-add it.
2. Delete the Host-only network and re-add it and restart virtual box.
3. Delete the Adapter from the VM and re-add it.
4. Restore the VM to a point before this adapter and add it.
5. Restart OSX.
6. Create a Host-only network that has not existed before `vboxnet3` and try to use that.

My host system is [osx](/questions/tagged/osx) and my guest system is [ubuntu](/questions/tagged/ubuntu). When I go into Ubuntu it tries to connect for a while but then just says wired network is disconnected.

[image]

Host system `ifconfig`:

```
vboxnet0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
        ether 0a:00:27:00:00:00 
        inet 192.168.56.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.56.255
```

Guest system `ifconfig`:

```
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:82:38:af  
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe82:38af/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:24 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:188 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:6901 (6.9 KB)  TX bytes:42262 (42.2 KB)
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hadn't configured a DHCP server for the Host-only net, once I had done that it worked fine. I'm not entirely sure why this was working for me once despite this, maybe I had managed to do it somehow.